# Spring boot test: MockedBean conflicts with others

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test, springmockito

Currently, I've two `RestTemplate` beans:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public RestTemplate jwtRestTemplate(
    RestTemplateBuilder builder,
    JWTService jwtService) {

        return builder
            .additionalInterceptors(
                Collections.singletonList(
                    new JWTHeaderRequestInterceptor(jwtService)
                )
            )
            .build();
}

@Bean
public RestTemplate rawRestTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    return builder.build();
}
```

The first one is primary and the other one is requested by `@Qualifier("rawRestTemplate")`.

However, I'm mocking a `ResTemplate` into my tests:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest()
public class AuditoryTest {

    @MockBean()
    private RestTemplate frontOfficeRestTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private DocumentServiceBackOffice documentService;
```

`DocumentServiceBackOffice` constructor is:

```
public DocumentServiceBackOffice(RestTemplate restTemplate);
```

I'm getting an exception:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc.backoffice.service.DocumentServiceBackOffice required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - rawRestTemplate: defined by method 'rawRestTemplate' in class path resource [net/gencat/transversal/espaidoc/backoffice/config/BackOfficeConfiguration.class]
    - jwtRestTemplate: defined by method 'createMock' in null


Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

Message is pretty clear, but I don't quite figure out how to solve that.

Any ideas?

Comment: Rename your field to `jwtRestTemplate ` or specify the `name` in `@MockBean`.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved that using that additional `Configuration` class:

```
@TestConfiguration
public static class RestTemplateTestConfiguration {

    @Bean("jwtRestTemplate")
    @Primary
    public static RestTemplate someService() {
        return Mockito.mock(RestTemplate.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try use `@MockBean(name = "jwtRestTemplate")` , instead of create addition test configuration class??